# hie i have been trying to develop my own trading robot using python, Can someone illustrate to me how to get live prices from deriv

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading

I need to use a socket stream API or any tools you know to get historical and live prices from my broker(Deriv) to my system server were the program will be hosted. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I use huobi api to build my bot.. below are some working codes:

```
import requests
import json
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import time

base_uri = 'api.huobi.pro'
AccessKeyId = 'xxxxxx'
SecretKey = 'xxxxxx'
account_id = '11111111'

def get_url(method, endpoint):
    timestamp = str(datetime.utcnow().isoformat())[0:19]
    params = urlencode({'AccessKeyId': AccessKeyId, 'SignatureMethod': 'HmacSHA256', 'SignatureVersion': '2', 'Timestamp': timestamp})
    pre_signed_text = method + '\n' + base_uri + '\n' + endpoint + '\n' + params
    hash_code = hmac.new(SecretKey.encode(), pre_signed_text.encode(), hashlib.sha256).digest()
    signature = urlencode({'Signature': base64.b64encode(hash_code).decode()})
    return 'https://' + base_uri + endpoint + '?' + params + '&' + signature

def get_all_open_orders():
    url = get_url('GET', '/v1/order/openOrders')
    response = requests.request('GET', url, headers={}, data={})
    return json.loads(response.text)['data']

def place_new_order(data):   #for both buy/sell
    url = get_url('POST', '/v1/order/orders/place')
    response = requests.request('POST', url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, data=data)
    return json.loads(response.text)

def cancel_order(order_id):
    url = get_url('POST', '/v1/order/orders/{}/submitcancel'.format(order_id))
    response = requests.request('POST', url, headers={}, data={})
    return json.loads(response.text)
```

To get current price

```
SYMBOL = 'xrphusd'
url = 'https://api.huobi.pro/market/history/kline?period=1min&size=1&symbol=' + SYMBOL
response = requests.request('GET', url, headers={}, data={})
print(json.loads(response.text)['data'][0])
```

To place an order (can be 'buy-limit' or 'sell-limit')

```
price = "1.25"
quantity = "100"
payload = {"account-id": str(account_id), "amount": quantity, "price": price, "source": "api", "symbol": SYMBOL, "type": "buy-limit"}
status = place_new_order(json.dumps(payload))
print(status)
```

Documentation available here https://huobiapi.github.io/docs/spot/v1/en